# Servidor de e-mail local com interface gráfica

Tags: email, envio-de-email

Durante o desenvolvimento das aplicações preciso testar o envio de e-mails, seria ótimo se pudesse ter um um servidor local com uma interface gráfica, dessa forma bastaria somente configurar minha aplicação para enviar e-mails para este servidor. Existe alguma ferramenta open source que possibilite isso?

Comment: Outra coisa que o site não é um repositório de *links* para ferramentas. Eventualmente elas podem existir como complemento mas apenas ficar citando ferramentas não é legal, inclusive podem até sinalizar sua resposta por só conter *link*.

Comment: Boa dica, mas existem alguns casos como este que fica difícil não explicar referenciando para links. Mas irei tomar cuidado da próxima vez!

Comment: O problema não é referenciar, é **só** referenciar. Respostas devem responder e não **apenas** *linkar*.

Comment: Sim, compreendo. Vou ser mais cauteloso. Tenho uma vontade de ajudar, estou procurando por perguntas sem resposta :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soluções citadas abaixo disponibilizam um servidor de e-mail com interface gráfica, facilitando o teste de envio de e-email em aplicações:

- [MailCatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/)
- [MailDev](https://github.com/djfarrelly/MailDev)
- [FakeSMTP](https://github.com/Nilhcem/FakeSMTP)

Espero ter ajudado :D